# where can I find the installed package

Tags: apt, package-management

I installed package `pidgin-skype-common` ?

I searched but I found many commands

I don't know which command should I use

package :

```
pidgin-skype-comon_20140930+svn665+dfsg-1_i386.deb
```

In windows, every program that we install gets its own directory inside ,
any ideas

How to install `pidgin` on Ubuntu or Debian  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install `pidgin` :

```
sudo apt-get install pidgin
```

Now the package `pidgin-skype-common` mainly provides two shared library files `libskype_dbus.so` and `libskype.so` to interface skype with pidgin. It has nothing to with any command.

You can see this by `dpkg -L pidgin-skype-common`:

```
$ dpkg -L pidgin-skype-common 
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/purple-2
/usr/lib/purple-2/libskype_dbus.so
/usr/lib/purple-2/libskype.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/pidgin-skype-common
/usr/share/doc/pidgin-skype-common/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/pidgin-skype-common/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/pidgin-skype-common/copyright
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common/icons
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common/icons/16
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common/icons/16/skypeout.png
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common/icons/16/skype.png
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common/icons/22
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common/icons/22/skypeout.png
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common/icons/22/skype.png
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common/icons/48
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common/icons/48/skypeout.png
/usr/share/pidgin-skype-common/icons/48/skype.png
```

Also if you run `dpkg -s pidgin-skype-common` you can see this in the `Description` section :

```
Description: Skype plugin for libpurple messengers (common files)
 This protocol plugin allows libpurple to communicate with Skype.
 Applications using libpurple (Pidgin, Finch, Empathy/Telepathy,
 etc.) can thus show your Skype contacts alongside those from
 other protocols, and you can communicate with them using that
 application instead of the Skype user interface.
```

Comment: @I'mV Accounts are generic..should work here too..if not (for some reason) knock me again..

Comment: in pidgin it's saying connecting for long time but it didn't connect to even IM account that i made on windows too but i stopped using it on windows

Comment: @I'mV Need to look at the configuration then..could you please ask it as a new question with all the details ?

Comment: which account are you using btw ?

Comment: finally it connected but after 10 min everytime that try to login it take 10-15 min !!

Comment: @I'mV Thats insane amount of time..probably you should start by debugging your connecticity, network etc first and then move all the way to pidgin..

Comment: more calcification please

Comment: I mean check the network latency to yahoo by e.g. `ping`, if that seems ok then check on pidgin..also if you have another account e.g. in hangout check how much does that take..

Comment: to skype it takes 1 sec :D To IM account that i created it takes 15 min :D

Comment: so it seems there could be a bug in pidgin that is triggering this..i see, here it is..it a proxy issue.. https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/12474 ..its an old ticket, how come it is not solved by now..worth making a new ticket..

Comment: they didn't solve it :D :D :D

Comment: @I'mV too bad ;)